# I have an error in Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, branding

Anyone know of an program that let me know if one XML or HTML file have a error in the schema?

I have an error in Master Page and I need know if the error is the schema.

Comment: You can do a preview of the HTML using Design manager

Comment: ok, but the problem happens when the site is in producction, the Master Page throw a error of design.